# If I have a huge memory on the system, what parameters should be changed in order to use the whole memory for hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hpc, in-memory

I have a 3TB of memory on a single machine. I'm running single node setup of hadoop. What all parameters should I change in order to utilize the whole memory?

What configuration parameters should I be tweaking/tuning?

When I run TeraSort Benchmark (with replication = 1), only teragen(1 TB) takes about 5 hours to run (this on a machine which has 3 TB of memory and 8 TB of storage). There must be a way to reduce the running time. I must be missing some configuration.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, why do you need Hadoop if you are not doing anything in parallel? (single node setup what the hell?) And when you have a single machine that has 3TB of RAM, you can just use any normal programming language and call its sort routine. Hadoop is a waste of anything here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know response would be something like this. :)
For now I'm running it on a single machine. Next, more similar machines will be added. Then, I suppose it will be like running hadoop on multiple big fat machines (as supposed to low budget machines for which hadoop is used traditionally)

My question is more like Hadoop on HPC.

I'm curious about knowing if the in-memory architecture can be used to run "hadoop applications" faster. It is more like moving from "hadoop on share-nothing architecture" to "hadoop on shared-memory" architecture"

Thanks